# Limit to tag edits?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

Is there a limit to how many time somebody can edit a post just to change the tags?

There is [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1048803/list) that is 19 days old that has been edited 17 times - mostly switching between the image/images tag - so it pops to the top of the page.

Whilst I can ignore this one user, it is going to get real annoying if others decide to play this game.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's any such limit, no.

However, if a post *does* keep being edited by just a few people, you can flag it for a moderator to investigate. They may well lock the post.

If the same user does this for lots of posts, they're likely to be warned and may eventually get in the [penalty box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

Answer (score 2):

If you're really bothered you could raise a flag on that post "Requires Moderator Attention" and explain why in the text box that appears.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a limit - however, flag it for a moderator and we'll intervene. I've locked the post in question; now I'll see if this is habitual...

Answer (score 2):

It appears this user is attempting to keep the question active by constantly making an edit. I would flag a moderator.